# Create new variable in data table based on conditions on other variables

Tags: r, comparison, data.table

I would like to create a new variable in a data table whose value depends on the relation of other variables of the data table. Let's say I have a data table with three variables:

```r
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(replicate(3,sample(0:2,5,replace=TRUE)))
DT
   V1 V2 V3
1:  0  2  1
2:  1  2  1
3:  2  0  1
4:  1  1  0
5:  1  0  0
```

I would like to create a new variable which is based on the following function:

```r
myfun <- function(a,b,c) {
  newvar = "x"
  if (a > b + c) {
    newvar = "a"
  }
  if (b > a + c) {
    newvar = "b"
  }
  if (c > a + b) {
    newvar = "c"
  }
  return(newvar)
}
```

I tried to apply the same logic that works with addition, etc., but here it fails.

```r
DT[, new_var := myfun(V1, V2, V3)]
```

It should be related to the different nature of addition and comparisons of vectors. What would be the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: I guess it doesn't work because the `if` operator is not vectorized. Instead, you can use `ifelse`.

Comment: @janosdivenyi Another option using `combn` `indx <- DT>DT[,3:1, with=FALSE][, combn(.SD, 2, FUN=function(x) x[[1]]+x[[2]])]; DT[, newcol:=c('x', letters[1:3])[as.vector(indx%*%seq_len(ncol(indx)))+1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition can be rewritten as

```
bigcol <- apply(2*DT > rowSums(DT),1,which)
```

since a > b+c is equivalent to 2a > a+b+c, and so on. Your new column is

```
DT[,newcol:=
  sapply(bigcol,function(x) if(length(x)==0) 'x' else letters[x])
]
```

---

A matrix might be the most natural way to store your data if this is the sort of thing you'll be doing with it. The approach here could be a little computationally simpler:

```
mat <- as.matrix(DT)
maxxer <- apply(mat,1,which.max)
newcol <- ifelse(
  2*mat[cbind(1:nrow(mat),maxxer)] > rowSums(mat),
  letters[maxxer],
  'x'
)
```

Only the largest column is a contender to replace x, so we can just compare it against the sum.

Comment: Unfortunately, my problem involves more complicated conditions: (`a + b + c > 0` & `a > 2*b`) identifies one group (`a + b + c > 0` & `b > 2*a`) identifies another, (`a + b + c > 0` but neither `a > 2*b` nor `b > 2*a`) identifies another and `a + b + c = 0` identifies the last. I cannot see any easy way to rewrite this.

Comment: Hm, maybe that deserves its own question...? I thought you meant you were actually using the function above not a function *like* the function above.

Comment: However, that again has a simple form: define the ratio `abrat <- a/b`; then use `ifelse(a+b+c==0,'z',letters[1:3][findInterval(abrat,c(0,.5,2))])` or something similar.

Comment: you still have to handle the case when `a = b = 0` and `c > 0`, and when `a > 0` but `b = 0` (thus, `a/b` is undefined), but thanks for the idea.

Comment: @janosdivenyi Oh, right. I think inserting a pair of checks would work, like `ifelse(a+b+c==0,'z',ifelse(b==0,ifelse(a==0,'c','a'),letters[1:3][findInterval(abrat,c(0,.5,2))]))`. This may be little better than the more straightforward `ifelse(a+b+c==0,'z',ifelse(a>2*b,'a',ifelse(b>2*a,'b','c')))`, though.